# I want to install both windows 7 and ubuntu 15.10 on my acer gateway ne-572 notebook. How can i do that?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7, 15.10, acer

I have 1TB hard drive and 4GB RAM. I want to know the whole procedure from scratch i.e. which OS to be installed first and how to make the partitions.
I'll be installing both OS from bootable usb drives.
Please help me out.

Comment: There are numerous installation tutorials available already. You must first determine whether Windows is installed in BIOS mode or in EFI mode (or which mode you want to use, if it's not already installed), then find an installation tutorial. You can't swing a cat on the Internet without hitting such a tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

- First boot into a Ubuntu Live Media.
- Do some research on [GPT](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/), [LVM](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm), and [EFI](http://www.linuxdeveloper.space/fix-partition-table-issues-win-linux/) etc. And decide your prefered
  partitioning scheme. For example you'd create separate partitions
  for..

  - Windows partition
  - Windows storage partition
  - Ubuntu root
  - Ubuntu home
- Create a new partition table using Gparted or a disk utility of your 
  choice.
- Boot into a Windows bootable media and continue with your
  installation.
- Disable fast startup.
- Install Ubuntu.
- Done.